# Details of an audio file in java

Tags: java, audio

I am new to JAVA and I want to know how to find the details of an audio clip that is stored on my computer.
Details like sample rate , frame size..
I have searched for the answer for hours , but could not find a satisfying answer.
Thanks.

Comment: This might help you: https://dzone.com/articles/how-retrieveextract-metadata

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this code that will print metadata for a wav file.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String filename = "/usr/share/lmms/samples/shapes/technosynth6.wav";
        File fileIn = new File(filename);
        try {
            AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
            System.out.println("format. " + in.getFormat());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
format. PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

Comment: @DacSanders
please tell me how to add the audio file in eclipse.. and also how to specify the path

Comment: @arjunsingh You should be able to just change the path `"/usr/share/lmms/samples/shapes/technosynth6.wav"` to a path to a wav file on your local storage.